# Reporting in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am new in laravel. I want to create report over my database. In project database I create a table named 'timelog'. I want to create report daily, weekly, monthly progress data of this table. How to do this?

Comment: open up your favorite editor and start writing?

Comment: What kind of report?  Where's the data for the report coming from?  Is the report going to be shown in a view?

Comment: This is really too generic. Depends on how you want it to work. The most of the time reports are simple views with a printable version.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which and how many queries were generated on each request with , you can use the wonderful [laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) i can't imagine myself developing laravel apps without it. (it slow your app a little bit)

Or, Assuming you are looking for a way to monitor your database/table CRUD stats, you need something like [newrelic](http://newrelic.com/php/laravel) , the good news is that they support [Laravel](http://laravel.com) with a dedicated package, it tells you which db Queries are hard on the system in real time, you just need a little more setup than laravel-debugbar and you can use it locally (like i do).